# Error with MTW: <Exception> in insert: thread is exiting

Tags: python, multithreading, dolphindb

When I used `MultiThreadTableWriter` provided by the dolphindb Python API to write data into a DolphinDB table, an error was reported: `<Exception> in insert: thread is exiting`, which is shown as follows.

[image]

I don’t know what might have caused this issue. Can someone provide insights into the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential causes for this issue:

1. The data being written may contain contain inconsistencies or
   mismatches in data types, which can cause the MTW to exit before the
   data insertion is completed.
2. Another possible reason is that you continue writing data after
   calling the `waitForThreadCompletion` function.